# How to get around Spring Integration fatal Error in int-xml:validating-filter?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a spring integration app that processes messages from a queue and sends them to a different queue.  It works great for all message types expected and as long as XML is valid.  I have an error channel defined to handle exception cases like validation failures, routing failures, etc.

For error testing, I dropped in an bad XML message with a mismatched tag to test the error handling.  Unfortunately, what I get in the console of eclipse is the following output:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:156: The end-tag for element type "Header" must end with a '>' delimiter
```

It does not route the message to the error flow, where the status would be updated to error from pending.

It seems like Spring Integration itself is unable to handle that scenario.  I would have expected an exception to occur and for it to route the message to the defined error channel.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

We are running Spring Integration 2.2.4, I tried 2.2.6 and got the same result.  The company framework we are using is on that version.  We are trying to get them to update to the latest, but it hasn't happened yet.

Comment: I'm just reviewing your posts in the Review section of SO, so I don't know what "Spring" is, but I think it might help people if you showed them your code so they could see how you're handling errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you try to build an XML `Document` manually and send it to the `<int-xml:validating-filter>`.

When I use:

```
return builder.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
            new InputSource(new StringReader("<greeting><other</greeting>")));
```

I end up with:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:17: Element type "other" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

It means that you can't create even a `Document` and and still not talking about a `validation`.

Try to send to the validator channel just String for your invalid xml. In this case I get:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: org.springframework.xml.validation.XmlValidationException: Could not validate source: Element type "other" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 17; Element type "other" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

And that means that I can handle a `MessageHandlingException` from some upstrem `error-channel`